# Register dll to gac as another user

Tags: c#, windows-7, uac, gac

I have an application that requeres to register a dll into a gac on a client computer everytime a new dll is deployed the problem is that the client computers only have restricted users with UAC turned on.

The application knows the credentials of a user that has admin rights.

The problem is if I have `processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` then I can't get trough the UAC getting the error "The requested opperation requires elevation"
and if I have  `processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` then it does not allow to run the whole thing as a different user: "The process object must have UseShellExecute property set to false in order to start the process as a user"

```
        internal static void Register(String assemblyName)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(lcDir + "gacutil.exe", string.Format("/i {0}.dll", assemblyName));
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = lcDir;
        processStartInfo.UserName = lcUser;
        processStartInfo.Password = Password;
        processStartInfo.Domain = lcDomain;

        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

I would like to know what the "Best practice" for that kind of thing is? I know the whoe concept looks to windows like a virus.

What I would like to achive the following:

- User dosen't need to know an account with admin rights
- The credencal's of the admin user are saved in the program's database
- As much as possable Automated registration.

Comment: ok looks like someone voted my question down without an explanation. Anyway ty Manuel Amstutz for the input but that dosen't seem to work since if I run the program like that I get the error unknown error if I run the whole app as with the admin account it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run this part of your code as Administrator.
What you need is impersonation.

See this article

[Aricle Impersonation on Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User)

Answer (score 0):

You are not meant to embed such user strings within an application for security reasons.

The design idea is that you deploy using System Management Services or similar to manage the deployment (which sucks).

I got round it my using private assemblies, very similar to the way unix works.

If you are looking to add class support in SQL Native Client, then you will find it is an uphill struggle to get deployed each time.

If you know a local administrator name and password, you could use a central deployment solution and not try to get your app to impersonate an administrator.

Comment: well the security aspect is served to some extent since the credentials are saved in the sql database as an encrypted string. And the sql server provides some level of protection. Anyway my usecase is something that should not exists I know that but it gets the job done.